# Get JSON in fragment one and save then show data in fragment tow

Tags: android, json, multithreading, android-fragments

In my app  I have two fragment in view pager
in Fragment 1 I have a list view, in item list view have :tile, image and a button
I want when I click button I can load JSON from sever and save it in a folder(file txt) of sd card and when  I click it again I can delete content in txt file
And with stored data  I can show it in fragment tow.
I did it by the following method without success: 
when I click button I start new thread request to JSON and have data,then I save it
But when I show two fragment I can't get it, when I restart my app I can get it
The problem occurs here is the thread that runs parallel to the activity and when I restart the application to get the results of thread
What measures have to take the results thread as soon as it has completed the download data? or Or any measures that might help me do it?
Thank so much

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you use shared preferences for acheiving this. Use a separate thread to download the json from server and directly save to shared preferences. Once you want to show the data on second fragment fetch it from shared preference.

Comment: problem is I want to store multiple entries to be viewed offline in fragment tow, whether shared preferences meets this requirement?

Comment: Yes of course.. Shared preference is a kind of persistent storage

Comment: Thank so much! I will try it, hope it will success